# Why using map to transform a list of strings into int gives me lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a simple problem. I want to transform a list of values into int

```
a = ['11', '12', '73']
```

So I applied:

```
[list(map(int, x) for x in a]
```

But, then I get a list of lists

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [7, 3]]
```

Why is that? I know strings are list objects, but in this case a has three elements. How can I do that?

Comment: Strings are not list they're iterable. You're applying the `int` function on each character.

Comment: use `list(map(int, a))`

Comment: Why the downvote? It was just ignorance, not a badly asked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list comprehension is redundant. What you are looking for is `list(map(int, a))`

By using map within your list comprehension, you are doing the list comprehension equivalent of the following:

```
[[int(x) for x in y] for y in a]
```

Which will always produce a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should be fine now:

```
list(map(int, a))
```